# Get HttpElement text

Tags: c#, browser

```
<div id="div1">
    <span>Span text 1</span>
    <span>Span text 2</span>
    Div Inner Text
</div>
```

How to extract only the div1 text (Div Inner Text)?

div1.innerText returns and the span's text.

Comment: C# and webbrowser? don't you mean Javascript? Also, what have you tried? It may help understand the how and what you're trying to do.

Comment: .NET WebBrowser component. Tried HttpElement.InnerText it returns inner tag's text. Tried to remove all child element, component has no such property or method.

Answer (score 0):

There are similar questions regarding fetching an element's inner text.

- Solution 1 : see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527499/webbrowser-control-get-element-value-and-store-it-into-a-variable)

  ```
  HtmlElement e1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementId");
  string content = e1.InnerText
  MessageBox.Show(content);
  ```
- Solution 2 : use Javascript using HtmlDocument.[InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be9zzz62.aspx) method

  In your HTML :

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function getInnerText(id) {
         return document.getElementById(id)..innerText;
      }
  </script>
  ```

  C#

  ```
  Object[] objArray = new Object[1];
  objArray[0] = (Object)"elementId";
  string content = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("getInnerText", objArray);
  MessageBox.Show(content);
  ```

Comment: Solution 1: This will strip any html tags and will return "Span text1 Span tex2 Div Inner Text". I want only the "Div Inner Text". Solution 2 is fine but I can not alter the source html.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take it to iterate over child nodes, test if each is a textnode and if it is store it in an array and then return the elements of the array concatenated.

```
  function innerText(element){
    var i, text = [], child = null;
    for(i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++){
      child = element.childNodes[i]

      if (child.nodeType === 3 &&
        child.nodeValue.match(/[^\n\s\t\r]/)){
        text.push(child.nodeValue);
      }
    }
    return text.join("");
  }
  // Example call
  alert(innerText(document.getElementById("div1")));
```

The code above uses the nodeValue property of DOMElements to check whether a node is a text node (nodeValue === 3) and that the element contains more than whitespace. The result could be tidied by trimming leading and trailing whitespace.

### Edit: C# use

Using Yanick's code as a template as it seems straight forward. Update the JavaScript function to;

```
  function innerText(id){

    var i, text = [], child = null, element = document.getElementById(id);
    for(i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++){
      child = element.childNodes[i]

      if (child.nodeType === 3 &&
        child.nodeValue.match(/[^\n\s\t\r]/)){
        text.push(child.nodeValue);
      }
    }
    return text.join("");
  }
```

Then it can be called using:

```
string content = 
  (string)webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("innerText", 
                                            new string[] { "div1" });
```

The variable `content` will contain the inner text value.
This doesn't check that the id passed to the function exists so additional checks would be required for a real world application.

Comment: This is fine for javascript, but how to access the DOM from .NET