# Reading data from HTML source file

Tags: c#, html, parsing

In this website : http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/Kazzak/Ierina/simple I want to get the value that says "560" item level.

I've done some research and I figured out how to get all source code with

```
string html = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/Kazzak/Ierina/simple");
```

and i think the value which i should read is here in the source code :

```
(<span class="equipped">560</span> Equipped)
```

or here :

```
<div id="summary-averageilvl-best" class="best tip" data-id="averageilvl">
        560
    </div>
```

I have tried getting that value by using this way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958449/3935085

My code :

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/Kazzak/Ierina/simple");
            HtmlElement ilvl = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("equipped");
            label1.Text = ilvl.InnerText;
```

However, ilvl returns as null.

Comment: `GetElementById()` will only retrieve elements by ID (not class name). This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8461952/453277

Comment: If you are retrieving it by an ID then use the second div ID you posted `summary-averageilvl-best`.

Comment: I have also noticed that my webBrowser1.DocumentText returns as "HTML></HTML>\0" would it be my problem ?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regular expression(regex).

```
string input = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/Kazzak/Ierina/simple");

// Here we call Regex.Match for <span class="equipped">560</span>
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"<span class=\""equipped\"">([0-9]+)</span>",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value; //result here

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you help. Your code fixed my problem and it is easy to understand. However, i am not really sure why did you type "([0-9]+)" in 'Regex.Match' parameters.

Comment: im thinking that the value "560" might be dynamic(changing).. "([0-9]+)" is regular expression for numeric value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/384478, give HtmlAgilityPack or SGMLReader a try instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can use  [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.Load("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/Kazzak/Ierina/simple")
var myValue = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class=\"equipped\"]");
```

Answer (score 1):

First Thing: you have a span with the **CLASS** `"equipped"` you are trying to get an element with the **ID** `"equipped"`

Second Thing:
You could try to use a [regular expression](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)