# Retrieve HtmlElement

Tags: c#, html

```
<a href="/game.php?yo=120252&amp;screen=info_command&amp;id=1602691855&amp;type=own">
<span class="element1">
    Random text 
</span>
```

I'm using a Windows-Forms-Application with an integrated webbrowser. Is there any way to retrieve this specific HtmlElement?

Sorry I'm very new to this, if there's some information missing please tell me.

Comment: Use `HTML Agility Pack`. Will make life much easier

Comment: What specific element? Neither have an ID. If it did you could use `GetElementById`, but since it doesn't you'd have to iterate through all tags of that class until you find what you want [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461932/how-to-getelement-by-class).

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527499/webbrowser-control-get-element-value-and-store-it-into-a-variable

Comment: @Equalsk "Random text" is a link label in my browser I want to click on and for that I need the HtmlElement. The link you provided doesnt work, using GetAttribute("className") == "element1"...

Comment: @fredw Unfortunately I don't have an ID, so this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;
...

var element1 = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
      .Where(e => e.GetAttribute("class") == "element1")
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

`element1` will be `null` if it wasn't found